Explain the topic in a way that a ten year old can understand

Explain the topic in a way that a ten year old can understand, please.

Explain the topic in a way that a ten year old could understand, please.

Explain the topic in a way that a ten year old would be able to understand, please.


Do these sentences convey the same meaning?

The word is so, not like.

This question is similar to: Are "could" and "would be able to" always interchangeable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Or in a way that.

@Lambie, that sentence is in past tense and mine are present tense sentences. Also, with my sentences, I'm trying to compare three modals "can", "could" and "would".

@KateBunting, but "so" and "in a way that" would give different meanings, wouldn't they?

@Lambie: Close, but no cigar! That linked Q only covers could and would be able to, not can. Mr X - I'd say there's no difference in meaning between your three sentences that's worth thinking about, Use whichever you like best. Nor would it make any difference with so instead of in a way that.

I'm starting to think 90% of ELL questions are about the differences between "can", "could" and "would be able" in irrealis and hypothetical constructions.

If there's no actual ten-year old nearby, the first with can implies more strongly than the others do that the person speaking is presenting themselves as having a ten-year-old's capacity to understand.  Akin to "explain it like I'm five".

Yes they convey the same meaning. There is at most a minuscule difference, if any. It is a matter of personal choice and taste.


Active voice, present tense, can.
Conditional voice of "can": could. Can and could are never used with other modals.
Condirional voice of "to be able" using conditional form of modal "will": would.


The modal "can" and verb phrase "to be able" both convey the sense of ability or capability, so they convey synonymous senses. So 2 and 3 are just synonyms for the same thing, both in the conditional voice.
The only distinction is that 2 and 3 are addressing clearly hypothetical situations, while 1 is addressing a situation which could by hypothetical or an actual present situation.

A child can understand the topic, right now, (if the situation arises).
A child could hypothetically understand the topic, (if the situation arose).
A child could hypothetically understand the topic, (if the situation arose).

The distinctions are very slight, as they all are addressing hypotheticals. One is a hypothetical in the active voice, and the others are dealing with hypotheticals in the voice particularly used for hypotheticals. A lot of questions arise from this situation of being able to convey the same meaning in different grammatical ways, apparently under the impression that different grammar must always have a different meaning.

Thanks. Corrected.

He can go. I'll allow it. Versus: He could go, if his mother allowed it. Not the same.

Yes, I didn't say there is never a distinction between subjunctive and active meanings. Obviously there is. However it's surprising how often sentences arise where, to all intents and purposes, the subjunctive meaning and a simple active meaning are indistinguishable. Or, at the very least, additional context is needed before any meaningful distinction can be discerned by the reader (such as your hypothetical mother).

I don't much like the term subjunctive. It's conditional.

Fair. I have replaced. I was using "subjunctive" as a kind of "generic irrealis", but that was incorrect
